# Как "блокировать" приложения после истечения лимита времени?

Tags: java, android

Делаю приложение, которое должно блокировать другие приложения, после окончания "лимита времени" (установленного пользователем).

Я понимаю, что отследить статистику использования приложений можно с помощью android.app.usage, но **я не понимаю как "блокировать" приложения.**
Нужно использовать "Lock task mode", Task Killer или что-то другое?

У меня базовые знания Java и Android, но мне нужно написать описание функционала и инструменты/методы, которые необходимы для реализации

Comment: `... должно блокировать другие приложения, после окончания "лимита времени"... ` пытаетесь встать на скользкий путь?

Comment: В плеймаркете есть подобные решения (ищутся по запросу "ограничение доступа к приложениям"). Во время использования мне показалось, что они не используют режим "Lock task mode", а просто сбрасывают задачи (как диспетчер задач). У меня задача сделать то же самое, сейчас я ищу с помощью чего такое можно реализовать

Comment: Недавно попался [вопрос с похожей темой](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19604097/killbackgroundprocesses-no-working). У меня есть предположение, что ответ на этот вопрос может мне подойти...